# Unexpected setTimeout in asyncData (nuxt/no-timing-in-fetch-data)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I'm trying to run a code from my pages/posts/index.vue page.  But I keep getting an error message saying: Unexpected setTimeout in asyncData'.  I don't know what that means.  Can someone please help?  Do I need any further plugins?

```
<template>
  <div class="postspage">
   <section class="introduction">
   </section>
   <PostList :posts="loadedPosts" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PostList from '@/components/Posts/PostList'

export default {

middleware: 'log',

components: {
PostList
},

asyncData (context, callback) {
setTimeout(() => {
callback(null, {
  loadedPosts: [
    {
      id: 'Post1',
      title: '1st post',
      previewText: 'This is post number 1',
      thumbnail: 'https://www.pexels.com/video/5899816/'
    },
    {
      id: 'Post2',
      title: '2nd post',
      previewText: 'This post number 2',
      thumbnail: 'https://www.pexels.com/video/5899816/'
    }
  ]
  })
 }, 1500)
},

 created () {}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expected that `asyncData` will return data directly, and that data will be merged into the component (page) `data`. You don't need to set a timer or invoke a callback. Try something like this:

```js
async asyncData () {
  return {
    loadedPosts: [
      {
        id: 'Post1',
        title: '1st post',
        previewText: 'This is post number 1',
        thumbnail: 'https://www.pexels.com/video/5899816/'
      },
      {
        id: 'Post2',
        title: '2nd post',
        previewText: 'This post number 2',
        thumbnail: 'https://www.pexels.com/video/5899816/'
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

You return an object from `asyncData` and can then access your data using `this.loadedPosts` elsewhere in component methods, or double curly braces in HTML templates like `<div>{{ loadedPosts }}</div>`.

If you need to *fetch* that data from an API, you can `await` the result of an API response. The Nuxt docs have more detail on that:
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Collin-Allen,  I've just tried this and it seems to work as well (just removed the setTimeout function:

```
asyncData (context, callback) {
callback(null, {
  loadedPosts: [
    {
      id: '1',
      title: 'First Post',
      previewText: 'This is my first post!',
      thumbnail: 'https://www.pexels.com/video/5899816/'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      title: 'Second Post',
      previewText: 'This is my second post!',
      thumbnail: 'https://www.pexels.com/video/5899816/'
    }
  ]
}, 1500)
```

},